# Why is no data being returned

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find majors that end with S, but no data is being returned

```
create table Student
 (sid char(10) primary key, 
  sname varchar(20) not null, 
  gpa float, 
  major char(10), 
  dob DATE);

insert into Student values('111', 'Joe', 3.5 , 'MIS', '01-AUG-2000');
insert into Student values('222', 'Jack', 3.4  , 'MIS', '12-JAN-1999');
insert into Student values('333', 'Jill', 3.2 , 'CS', '15-MAY-1998');
insert into Student values('444', 'Mary', 3.7 , 'CS', '17-DEC-2001');
insert into Student values('555', 'Peter', 3.8 , 'CS', '19-MAR-1999');
insert into Student values('666', 'Pat', 3.9,  'Math', '31-MAY-2000');
insert into Student values('777', 'Tracy', 4.0,  'Math', '18-JUL-1997');

SELECT * FROM STUDENT
WHERE MAJOR LIKE '%S'
```

This doesn't work on livesql (oracle (PL-SQL) based but works on T-SQL).

This is the error message: 'No data found'

Answer (score 3):

Your CHAR(10) will always contain 10 characters so it is going to be padded with space characters.  Change to VARCHAR2(10) and it will work.  I'm assuming Oracle since you didn't specify which database.  But VARCHAR(10) should work with T-SQL.

Comment: Correction on my comment.  I see that you did specify Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't (or won't) modify datatype to `varchar2` (not `varchar` as Stilgar suggested), then trimming the column might help:

```
SQL> select * from student
  2  where trim(major) like '%S';

SID        SNAME                       GPA MAJOR      DOB
---------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- --------
111        Joe                         3,5 MIS        01.08.00
222        Jack                        3,4 MIS        12.01.99
333        Jill                        3,2 CS         15.05.98
444        Mary                        3,7 CS         17.12.01
555        Peter                       3,8 CS         19.03.99
```

Comment: Yep, I forgot that char consumes space regardless